# Django coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.date found

Tags: django, datetime, unicode

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    recorded_on = models.DateField()
    precipitation = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

in my views I have a query thus:

```
import datetime

def my_view(request):
    ...
    format = '%Y-%m-%d' 
    sd = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdate, format)
    ed = datetime.datetime.strptime(enddate, format)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter((recorded_on__range = (sd, ed)))
    ...
```

But whenever I try and do anything with the queryset (e.g. json dump, display in template), I get the following error:

```
    coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.date found
```

I know there must be an easy way to deal with this, but I have not yet found it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

An example of data:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | recorded_on | precipitation |
+----+-------------+---------------+
| 24 | 1987-07-02  |          20.7 |
| 33 | 1987-07-11  |           0.4 |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please show the actual traceback. Which line is causing the error?

Comment: are you by any change trying to concatenate `recorded_on` with unicode string using `+` operator? If so, the way to do it is `u"a string" + str(obj.recorded_on)`

Comment: My traceback is somewhat different from the post, as I have simplified it - I suspect this is a general problem. But the line of my code that django complains about is the views.py line which renders to template. Link here: http://dpaste.com/722851/ .I also tried the query in the shell and just trying to print or iterate the queryset gives the same error.

Comment: I am not concatenating. As I mentioned, I run the query in the shell and try: `>>> list(queryset)` which gives the same coercion error. So I guess I need to act directly on the queryset before I can do anything with it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You haven't shown the full code, but I suspect the problem is with your model's `__unicode__` method. This needs to return an actual unicode string - if you are just doing `return self.recorded_on` that will fail with the given error. Try something like `return unicode(self.recorded_on)`, or use `strftime` to convert to your desired date formatting, for example `self.recorded_on.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou. I actually had no idea the problem could be with the model!